# Unable to line radio buttons from Vertical to Horizontal with Bootstrap CSS no JS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have my `radio buttons` line up horizontally instead of lining up under each other. The reason for this is because I am in an `iFrame` and it is cutting off the rest of my page. If anyone can give me a hand that would be greatly appreciated!

---

https://jsfiddle.net/6y3hhdzc/

I have just basic `bootstrap css` with no `js`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
class="radio"
```

use

```
class="radio-inline"
```

Comment: Ahh, gosh so simple - thank you again for your help!